# Can't send emails with the new v3 Sendgrid API using NodeJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, email, sendgrid

I'm trying to send an email but it isn't going through. 
I used your example on README and also used the non Helper method one but none of them seems to work.

```
import { mail } from 'sendgrid';
const helper = mail;
const from_email = new helper.Email('admin@test.com');
const to_email = new helper.Email('someuser@test.com');
const subject = 'Testing';
const content = new helper.Content('text/plain', 'Test Description');
const email = new helper.Mail(from_email, subject, to_email, content);
const sg = require('sendgrid')(process.env.SENDGRID_API_KEY);
const request = sg.emptyRequest({
  method: 'POST',
  path: '/v3/mail/send',
  body: email.toJSON()
});
sg.API(request, function(error, response) {
  console.log(response.statusCode);
  console.log(response.body);
  console.log(response.headers);
});
```

The first `console.log` spits out the `statusCode` of `202`.
The second `console.log` spits out nothing.
The last `console.log` spits out this:

```
 { 
     server: 'nginx',
     date: 'Mon, 15 Aug 2016 08:59:42 GMT',
     'content-type': 'text/plain; charset=utf-8',
     'content-length': '0',
     connection: 'close',
     'x-message-id': 'kQdayBbvSKSb9ZlVDCUKTg',
     'x-frame-options': 'DENY' 
}
```

Comment: Did you find out why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**For anyone having similar issue.**

My account was apparently deactivated as I hadn't logged in to answer their support query. So what you need to do is to contact their support team.